# get input value from form doesnt work Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm currently used modal form and when the modal is open he load the information  of my items but when I want to submit all inputs are null
this is my modal "this part works fine"

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <form #formData='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData)">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input (ngModel)="productN" value="{{ObjProd.product}}"  name="productN" type="text"  >
          <label for="productN">Product Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input (ngModel)="price" value="{{ObjProd.price}}"  name="price" type="text"  >
          <label for="price">price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input (ngModel)="quantity" value="{{ObjProd.quantity}}"   name="quantity" type="text"  >
          <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input (ngModel)="photoURL" value="{{ObjProd.product}}"   name="photoURL" type="text"  >
          <label for="photoURL">photoURL</label>

        </div>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" value="{{ObjProd.key}}" (ngModel)="namef" name="namef" class="txt" >
        <input type="text" (ngModel)="keyProduct"   name="keyProduct" value="{{ObjProd.key}}" >
        <input type="text" (ngModel)="typeProduct"   name="typeProduct" value="{{ObjProd.type}}" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit"  class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat " >Update Product</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and this is my function Submit

```
  onSubmit(formData) {
    if(formData.value.typeProduct){
      console.log(formData.value.photoURL);
    }else{
      console.log(formData.value.namef, formData.value.photoURL);
    }

    }
```

this is my modal works and my data
but the output doesnt work 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/of1l9.jpg

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: when i press the button submit formData.value.typeProduct = null and also all inputs inside of my form

Comment: this is my output  [img](http://imgur.com/a/NanED) when i load my data from my component  [img](http://imgur.com/a/P7Oyp)

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8X0tgnDprWFJ0V9OrFOs?p=info

Comment: what is that you are doing in your plunker? why do you have your code in the index.html?

Answer (score 0):

You are having the code in the index.html and using jQuery and messing up the application.

Instead you should be using modal component as a separate component as below

```
import {Component,Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'common-modal',
  template: `
   <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form #formData='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData)">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="row">    
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input [(ngModel)]="productN" value="true"  name="productN" type="text"  >
          <label for="productN">Product Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input [(ngModel)]="price" value="true"  name="price" type="text"  >
          <label for="price">price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input [(ngModel)]="quantity" value="true"   name="quantity" type="text"  >
          <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input [(ngModel)]="photoURL" value="true"   name="photoURL" type="text"  >
          <label for="photoURL">photoURL</label>

        </div>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Full name" value="true" [(ngModel)]="namef" name="namef" class="txt" >
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="keyProduct"   name="keyProduct" value="true" >
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="typeProduct"   name="typeProduct" value="true" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit"  class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat " >Update Product</button>
    </div>
  </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class CommonModalComponent {
   @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
   @Input() title?:string;
  constructor() {
  }
  show(){
    this.childModal.show();
  }
  hide(){
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
  onSubmit(val){
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WTIdCwB07gpzbR1d6xFz?p=preview)**

Comment: https://github.com/H4isan/GloriaApps this is my repo,  the route is /inventory You misunderstood me, I put everything in the index but of course I did not do that to put everything in the html

Comment: what is that you exactly face?

Comment: Go to /inventory page, and go take de edit button when i open my modal  the information is loaded  but when  i do submit Does not return anything

Comment: instead of **`(ngModel)`** use `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: what is that you are getting as error? Also you can use this `formData.productN` instead of `productN` and let me know if it is working

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?